# ModBus RS485 adapter for GPIO

Tags: modbus

I have just purchased my first Raspberry Pi 2B.

We plan on using it to develop a standalone application with a very high reliability requirement (isolated locations).

Is it possible to connect it to the GPIO header, or is a usb converter the only solution ?